# Focus or Scroll to a particular div in a gsp template of a gsp page

Tags: grails, gsp

I created a gsp page in which i have 3 different templates and every template have a next button and on click of next button 1st template is hide and next template is visible
I want to focus on a particualar div when template is rendered using next button
Right now in template i tried using this but it does not work

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $('#mydiv').focus();
    });
```

Comment: Focusing on a div doesn't really do anything that's visible in the interface.  What do you mean when you say you want to focus on it?

Comment: i have a list of records which i am rendering on the bottom of the template so whenever the particular template is rendered i want to scroll down to that list of records which is in a div

Comment: You may want to look at `scrollIntoView()` rather than `focus()`.  You would still need to call this when rendering is complete rather than when the document is initially ready, if you're loading additional content via .load or similar.